# nosetests parallel testing doesn't work

Tags: python, nose, python-unittest

My test suite has a lot of tests. I normally do `nosetests --exe`, which takes a while. I discovered nose has parallel testing, so I tried `nosetests --exe --processes=4`, but nothing happens. I don't get the `...E.F.` progress bar or any messages at all.

Here is what happens when I use `--verbosity=3`

```
source parcel_env/bin/activate && \
    nosetests --verbosity=3 --processes=4
nose.config: INFO: Ignoring files matching ['^\\.', '^_', '^setup\\.py$']
```

Comment: Try running with `-v3` to see what is going on with nose internals. Does it quit or does it hang indefinitely?

Comment: @Oleksiy oops, missed your comment. I tried `nosetests --exe --processes=4 -v3`, but all I got was `nosetests: error: no such option: -3`

Comment: @Oleksiy I updated my post with what happens when I add  `--verbosity=3`. It just hangs.